# How can I disable HTTP compression via .htaccess on Apache webservers, May 2023

Tags: php

I have used many hours now to try to disable the HTTP compression on an apache webserver, but they will not work for me.

I have tried with the following code in my .htaccess-file:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>
```

---

When it is said I am not sure if my webhost have this module enabled or not.

I also have tried with the following code in my .htaccess-file:

```
RewriteRule . - [E=no-gzip:1]
```

And this code:

```
SetEnv no-gzip 1
```

---

When I go to my webhost tests server, where I can see all default informations about there servers - direct link: http://linux1.unoeuro.com/phpinfo.php
, I can see that my webhost have an Apache server with LiteSpeed. So I not understand why I not can disable the HTTP Compression.

I will disable the HTTP Compression for all files in the folder on a test domain called test1, and all files in the public_html folder. There is one .htaccess-file on both folders.

Do you have a idea about why I not can disable HTTP Compression via .htaccess, and a solution that I can try (e.g. via .htaccess or php.ini file)?

Comment: See here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/61259